# changing from SerializerMethodField() to annotate()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am new to django and django-rest-framework and I encounter a project where I need to optimize an API endpoint. Found that a SerializerMethodField() is causing a duplicate queries on SQL which I think is a N+1 problem. I am currently reading and trying to explore annotate() but found the logic computation to be complicated and I am stuck on how can I convert this to annotate(). Does anyone have a an idea on how to properly implement this? Please see the below code. Hope anyone can guide me as I already am stuck for several days on this. Thank you very much.

serializer.py:

```
class BootcampClassStatisticsSerializer(ModelBaseSerializer):
    attendance_rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_attendance_rating(self, instance):
        attendance_rating = None
        attendance_count = 0
        present_count = 0

        bootcampers = instance.bootcamper_set.all()
        date = self.context.get('date')

        for bootcamper in bootcampers:
            attendances = bootcamper.dailyattendance_set.all()
            if date:
                attendances = attendances.filter(date=date)

            present_attendances = attendances.filter(status=constants.PRESENT)
            if instance.class_type == constants.DAY:
                attendance_count += len(attendances) * 2
                for item in present_attendances:
                    if item.duration == 'wd':
                        present_count += 2
                    if item.duration == 'hd':
                        present_count += 1

            if instance.class_type == constants.NIGHT:
                attendance_count += len(attendances)
                present_count += len(present_attendances)

        if attendance_count:
            attendance_rating = round(present_count / attendance_count * 100, 2)

        return attendance_rating

    class Meta:
        model = BootcampClass
        fields = (
            'id',
            'batch_number',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'class_type',
            'attendance_rating'
```

views.py:

```
class BootcampClassStatisticsList(APIView):
    queryset = BootcampClass.objects.all()
    serializer = BootcampClassStatisticsSerializer()
    return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: hello, you could probably improve the number of query with 
`queryset = BootcampClass.objects.all()` => 
`queryset = BootcampClass.objects.prefetch_related('dailyattendance_set').all()` not like that, but using your own contraint in the view via the method get_queryset, probably with a Prefetch primitive , look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects . this will not resolve your main issue, but its a way to optimize this code.

Comment: about your main issue , take a look to : 
- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html
- https://hakibenita.com/django-group-by-sql